# How to get azimuth and altitude from a 3D surface in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, 3d, azimuth

I would like to know the azimuth and tilt of a polygon / surface in a PostGIS database. The azimuth should be given e.g. from 0° to 360° degrees. The altitude should be between 0° to 90°. An example result table:

```
sid | azimuth | tilt | geom
---------------------------
 0  |     0   |   0  | ...
 1  |    90   |  45  | ...
```

So `sid 0` would represent a north facing wall and `sid 1` a East facing roof with a 45° degree slope.

**Update:**
I guess the typical approach would look as follows:

1. Find the surface's centroid
2. Project a point North of it
3. Measure the azimuth and angle between the centroid and the projected point

After giving it some more thought and taking into account that all of the involved functions ([`ST_Centroid`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Centroid.html), [`ST_Project`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Project.html), and [`ST_Azimuth`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Azimuth.html)) are not 3D capable, I feel like this may currently not be possible in PostGIS.

Comment: [ST_Slope](http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Slope.html) might help you too, though that works on a raster.